# Распознавание речи google

Tags: java, android, распознавание-речи, google-speech-recognition

1) Как сделать что бы Java программа распознавания речи google под Android работала без остановки? Т.е. обычно при относительной тишине ~2 сек распознавание прекращается, а мне нужно что бы оно продолжало работать. Или как намного увеличить это время?

2) Как увеличить чувствительность микрофона при распознавании речи?

Comment: А что вы уже пробовали? Что за "java программа распознавания речи"?

Comment: @selya, видимо он имеет ввиду `okey Google`, но там такой возможности не видел. А если по другой программе, то автор, потрудись описать подробнее и если есть исходные коды, то будьте любезны предоставить те части. где происходит распознавание или микрофон.

Comment: Да, ребята, это okey Google! =) Делаю диктофон - звук в текст.

Comment: миллиард туториалов же есть

Comment: миллиард долларов тоже есть